# Ef Core 6 Data seeding from an external source

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, seeding, ef-core-6.0

I am trying to seed my data with `builder.HasData()` method. But my data is coming from an external api source. I wrote an extension method for `EntityTypeBuilder` class

```
public static async Task SeedDataAsync(this EntityTypeBuilder<MyModel> builder)
{
       var mySeedData = new Dictionary<string, string>();
       using (var client = new HttpClient())
       {
            var response = await client.GetAsync("https://myapi.com");
            var responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            mySeedData = JObject.Parse(responseBody).SelectToken("exampleFieldName").ToObject<Dictionary<string, string>>();
       }

       foreach (var item in mySeedData.Select((c, i) => (c, i)))
       {
            builder.HasData(new MyModel { Id = item.i + 1, MyFirstField = item.c.Key, MySecondField = item.c.Value });
       }
}
```

I am calling this extension method inside my configuration class

```
   public class MyModelConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<MyModel>
   {
      public async void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<MyModel> builder)
      {
          builder.HasKey(x => x.Id);
          //Some other configurations...

          await builder.SeedDataAsync();
      }
   }
```

And my OnModelCreating..

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        //Some other configurations...
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new MyModelConfiguration());
    }
```

Finally when i try to add a migration, i am having this error:

`Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: Metadata changes are not allowed when the model has been marked as read-only`

When i give dummy datas in this example instead of an api call, there is no problem. But if try to read data from an external api like given example, it is giving me same error always. I think that ef core couldn't read from external sources when we try to add a migration. What's your opinions?

Comment: There's a lot of problems with the approach you are taking.  1) `public async void Configure`: notice the `async void` there?  That's typically a big no-no.  The caller of `Configure` is unable to wait for your API work to finish, which is probably causing the error.  2) Despite appearances, calling `HasData` doesn't actually populate the database.  It's intended to allow EF to create a migration file with that data.  Therefore, you should just manually add a migration and create a SQL script (calling `.Sql(...)`)by using the repsonse from the API.

Comment: Thank you sir, you are right, i am aware of async void problem. But i couldn't mark it as a Task because of interface that i implemented. So what's your suggestion in this case? Should i add my datas over context instead of HasData method? when we think that i am intended to use ef core instead of sql scripts

Comment: My suggestion is to avoid `HasData` for your particular use-case, as it was never designed to be data driven from an external API.  Instead follow my above suggestion and create a new migration (`Add-Migration SeedData`) and in that empty migration file, add a line `migrationBuilder.Sql(...)`.  The SQL you pass to it should be a string that you generate (i.e. a series of `INSERT INTO` statements) based off the JSON response you receive from the API.

Comment: And yes, EF typically lets you avoid hand slinging SQL, but I believe your use-case is an exception.

Comment: Alternatively, you can generate the equivalent C# calls for `.HasData` based on the same technique, and simply paste the generated code into your class.

Comment: Your suggestion is more useful sir, thank you very much!